# dns (udp) proxy using kong

Tags: udp, dns-hosting, kong

I need to proxy DNS requests based on hostname.
[image]

I've configured the Kong to stream 53 udp.

I can create service:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"jerry", "protocol":"udp", "host": "jerry-coredns", "port": 53}'
```

But when trying to create a route based on hostname:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8001/services/jerry/routes \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"jerry-dns-route", "hosts": ["jerry.kong.local"], "destinations":[{"port":53}],"protocols":["udp"]}'
```

The Kong response is:

```
cannot set 'hosts' when 'protocols' is 'tcp', 'tls', 'tls_passthrough' or 'udp'
```

We know there's no hostname header on UDP protocol like HTTP.
So the question is, How do cloud providers like Cloudflare or Amazon, create the DNS server for their customers?
I can't use valid IP addresses per DNS server Obviously.

Comment: *"We know there's no hostname header on UDP protocol like HTTP."* - You cannot compare UDP (transport level) with HTTP (application level). You could compare UDP with TCP - both don't have the domain information. Or you could compare DNS with HTTP - both have the domain information: The DNS query contains what name is looked up.  But you don't use a proxy like Kong to handle DNS, instead you use a DNS server. Distribution of directory information over many DNS servers including caching is how DNS works, no "proxies" needed.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich for explaining OSI model and layers and protocols locations. But i need to proxy DNS traffic to correct dns server based on the ns server host address not the dns query. There's no host address in DNS header.How Can send dns traffic to the vorrect upstream? this the main question.

Comment: The HTTP host header does not have the host "address" either - it has only a host name which then can be used to explicit route it to some upstream server by the reverse proxy. Similar a forwarding DNS server can be configured to route queries for a specific domain (or multiple domains) to some upstream DNS server. Again, this is not something Kong can do, but something a forwarding DNS server can do - see for example [DNSMasq forwarding on specific domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004054/dnsmasq-forwarding-on-specific-domains)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for the decriptions you've made. Finally i found that i can't use private IP addresses for internal dns servers. I've used dnsmasq with server directive, e.g.: ```server=/jerry.myns/coredns``` but it needs to define a valid IP address for ```jerry``` itself to be public discoverable. So dnsmasq just forwards the DNS, not Proxy it.